In Rmarkdown for Word, how do you specify font for r output?
I found this helpful guide on how to use specify fonts for Rmarkdown files, but it left out I would change the font/style for R chunks with text. I've tried 2 options, shown in the sample rmarkdown script below. The first attempt runs but does nothing; the second crashes. Any guidance would be incredibly helpful!
---
title: "test"
output: word
  reference_docx: my_styles.docx
date: "2024-04-25"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

:::{custom-style="Style1"}
This works!
:::

:::{custom-style="Style1"}
```{r attempt 1}
cat(paste0("Wrapping an R chunk in the style runs," "but it doesn't apply the style!"))
```
:::

```{r attempt 2, custom-style="Style1"}
cat(paste0("Putting the style INSIDE the r brackets," "causes an error saying that R can't parse"))
```



Changing Fonts in Rmarkdown -> to Microsoft is not currently supported but it is supported if you were wanting export to a PDF.

A potential workaround would be to output the text inline instead of as chunk output:
---
title: "test"
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: my_styles.docx
date: "2024-04-25"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

:::{custom-style="Style1"}
This works!
:::

:::{custom-style="Style1"}
```{r attempt 1}
cat(paste0("Wrapping an R chunk in the style runs, but it doesn't apply the style!"))

x <- "But assigning text to a variable and outputting it inline does work."
```
:::

:::{custom-style="Style1"}
`r x`
:::

